# cannot move <filename> to <foldername>: permission denied

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I am attempting to move all files from one folder to another by using command:
`mv folder1name/* folder2name`.
However, it gives the error `cannot move 'filename' to 'folder2name': permission denied.`
I saw a video where someone used `sudo` beforehand, but I still get the same error when I try that.
I'm sure I'm missing something simple and subtle, but I can't seem to find exactly what I need.

Comment: what are the permissions of the files you're moving and the folder you're moving to?

Comment: This question is not about programming.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware that one of the main criteria for questions on this site is that they be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackoverflow.com), but please be sure to familiarize yourself with those sites' rules for posting as well.  I'd recommend deleting it here and moving it over to one of the other sites before the mods close it.  It won't count "against" your rep if you do it yourself before downvotes or closure.